# Ansible lineinfile with list to set ntp servers

Tags: loops, ansible

I want to add some lines to a file (they are ntp servers in /etc/ntp.conf).  Unfortunately, I can't use a template for various reasons.
so I have a variable like so:

```
vars:
- dns:
  - "{ 'region': 'syd', 'dns_servers': ['1.2.3.4', '2.3.4.5', '3.4.5.6' ] }"
  - "{ 'region': 'lon', 'dns_servers': ['2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3', '4.4.4.4' ] }"
  - "{ 'region': 'ny',  'dns_servers': ['5.5.5.5', '6.6.6.6', '7.7.7.7' ] }"
- ntp:
  - { 'region': 'syd', 'ntp_servers': ['syd1.pool.ntp.org','syd2.pool.ntp.org','syd2.pool.ntp.org'] }
  - { 'region': 'lon', 'ntp_servers': ['lon1.pool.ntp.org','lon2.pool.ntp.org','lon2.pool.ntp.org'] }
  - { 'region': 'ny',  'ntp_servers': ['ntp1.pool.ntp.org','ntp2.pool.ntp.org','ntp2.pool.ntp.org'] }
```

So there's 2 lists there; dns and ntp.  Each list contains a dictionary of region -> server mappings.

I want to iterate over the (in this case the ntp list) list to add a line for each ntp server in turn.   I've discovered the loop_control parameter to a loop construct, which allows me to set an offset into the ntp_servers list.

Here's one attempt I'm making to loop over the elements of the list in the dictionary:

```
- name: Replace ntp servers in /etc/ntp.conf
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item[loop_count] }}"
    loop: "{{ ntp['region']['ntp_servers'] }}"
    loop_control:
      index_var: loop_count
    when: item.region == region
```

(As an aside, how do you feel about using 'i' as the loop counter variable? )

I know this would be much easier with a template, and that lineinfile is an antipattern, but I am constrained by issues outside of my control.

The problem I have is that I want to loop over the items of the ntp_servers array, but my loop is looping over the ntp dictionary.  I've tried various combinations, but suspect that I'm using the wrong data structure - can anyone advise, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i see an issue with the `vars` structure. you should remove the hyphen from the `ntp` and `dns` variable declaration:

vars:
  ntp:
   .....
  dns: 
   .....

Also, the double quotes in the `dns` list elements, are making the elements considered as strings, `ntp` look ok.

to get all 9 ntp servers of the `ntp` variable in a list, so you can process in a loop, you can use the expression (feel free to remove the `sum(start=[])` and final `list` conversion, and then add them back to see why i used them):

`"{{ ntp | map(attribute='ntp_servers') | list | sum(start=[]) | list }}"`

example playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    ntp:
      - { 'region': 'syd', 'ntp_servers': ['syd1.pool.ntp.org','syd2.pool.ntp.org','syd2.pool.ntp.org'] }
      - { 'region': 'lon', 'ntp_servers': ['lon1.pool.ntp.org','lon2.pool.ntp.org','lon2.pool.ntp.org'] }
      - { 'region': 'ny',  'ntp_servers': ['ntp1.pool.ntp.org','ntp2.pool.ntp.org','ntp2.pool.ntp.org'] }

  tasks:
    - name: print
      debug: 
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      with_items: 
        - "{{ ntp | map(attribute='ntp_servers') | list | sum(start=[]) | list }}"
```

output:

```
TASK [print] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "syd1.pool.ntp.org"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "syd2.pool.ntp.org"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "syd2.pool.ntp.org"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "lon1.pool.ntp.org"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "lon2.pool.ntp.org"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "lon2.pool.ntp.org"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "ntp1.pool.ntp.org"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "ntp2.pool.ntp.org"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "ntp2.pool.ntp.org"
}

PLAY RECAP
```

Comment: Thanks - your answer, together with something a colleague suggested gave me what I wanted.  I'll post it when I get a moment.